# Make image visible from selected row inside listview android

Tags: android

In my application, i am trying to make holder.image visible at the selected row inside my ListView. My listview adapter is as follows:

called in my onCreate() activity but i can't set holder.image to visible from onCreate() activity. To be true, i don't know how to do it. Anyone already done this ? Please share your knowledge with me. thanks you in adavance.

Answer (score 1):

SetTag on imageview and when onItemClick You will get the view and find the imageview using tag and apply visibility.

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside the getView()

holder.image.setVisibility(vi.VISIBLE);

Comment: i get Multiple markers at this line
 - The static field View.VISIBLE should be accessed in a static way this error: 
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable vi inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method

Comment: use View.VISIBLE as VISIBLE is a constant field in the View class

Comment: i use v.VISIBLE but only the first and two last row in the listview becomes visible.

Comment: holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
give the same result

Comment: i solved it using      v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 thanks for your response